# Is testing for .Any() elements more or less efficient than trying to iterate an empty list?

Tags: c#

Which is more efficient - to attempt to iterate an empty list, or to test if there are any items in the list before attempting to iterate?

For example, first get an empty list of things:

```
var listOfThings = GetZeroThings(); // this returns 0 things
```

is it less efficient to attempt to execute this:

```
foreach (var thing in listOfThings)
{

}
```

or should I test whether there are any items? e.g.

```
if (listOfThings.Any())
{
    foreach (var thing in listOfThings)
    {

    }   
}
```

Comment: I think it would come down to the IL the compiler emits.  I would imagine (without having looked at the source code) that internally `.Any()` loops through the collection just like a `foreach` would.

Comment: It depends on your input. If most of time `listOfThings` are not empty, why should you care about performance of checking Any()? Direct `foreach` loop is good enough, both for performance and code readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [Any's source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0):

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) 
{
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (e.MoveNext()) return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

You can see that all it's doing is to call `GetEnumerator` on the source collection and call `MoveNext` method. The `foreach` will do exactly the same for an empty collection so, calling `Any` before `foreach` is redundant. But I believe it won't make any significant affect in terms of performance and I think using `Any` before `foreach` makes the code more readable.

Comment: I would disagree that the code is more readable with a redundant check. It's pretty obvious what happens to a foreach loop with an empty collection..

Comment: Calling `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` allocates an object. If you use a foreach loop against a concrete type such as `List<T>`, it will use a special version of `GetEnumerator` that uses a struct instead. If you are seeing a lot of GC cycles this could help. (Then again, if you know you have a List<T> just check the count.)

Comment: Agreed with @Blorgbeard,  compiler just required to know it is not  null to get the enumerator to loop.

Answer (score 2):

My simple test shows that the one with `Any` is slower:

```
[2016-04-18 03:01:55.900 UTC] Without Any: 254 ms
[2016-04-18 03:01:56.266 UTC] With Any: 363 ms
```

The code is below (may not be reproducable since you do not have my component `logBox`, but is included to show the fairness of the test):

```
IEnumerable<int> listOfThings = new List<int>();
logBox.GetTimeLapse();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
    foreach (var thing in listOfThings)
        Console.WriteLine("Do something!");
logBox.WriteTimedLogLine("Without Any: " + logBox.GetTimeLapse());
logBox.GetTimeLapse();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
    if (listOfThings.Any())
        foreach (var thing in listOfThings)
            Console.WriteLine("Do something!");
logBox.WriteTimedLogLine("With Any: " + logBox.GetTimeLapse());
```

Which I think is making sense because of the present of extra `Any` while your `foreach (var thing in listOfThings)` alone would have already done the checking for you anyway.

**Edit:**

Additional note by [Jonathan Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5274/jonathan-allen) which I think is worth included: The line `if (listOfThings.Any())` (1) allocates memory and (2) makes a virtual dispatch call. The line `foreach (var thing in listOfThings)` does neither.

Comment: The line `if (listOfThings.Any())` allocates memory and makes a virtual dispatch call. The line `foreach (var thing in listOfThings)` does neither.

Answer (score 1):

You need to profile it. It's really impossible to give you an answer. That being said, checking `Any()` looks like it *can* cause issues.

For example:

```
void Main()
{
    var listOfThings = GetThings();
    if (listOfThings.Any())
    {
        foreach (var item in listOfThings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<int> GetThings()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    yield return 1;
}
```

Assuming the first element is expensive to get, you're doing the work twice. It entirely depends on how your collection behaves. As above, you need to profile your own circumstances.

Just by looking at it, it seems like `Any()` will always be redundant, as it grabs the enumerator anyway.